# colcon build ros1_bridge not producing executable

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

UPDATE: my original question was about `colcon build` parameters, but thanks to the answer I discovered that the problem was not there.
Hence I have adjusted a little bit the question for future reference.

Hi,

I'm basically following the ROS2 official documentation for installing from sources ([reference here](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup)).

When I build the workspace using

```
colcon build
```

It looks like ros1_bridge executables are not installed.

If I source everything using

```
source install/setup.zsh
```

The output of `ros2 pkg list` shows `ros1_bridge`, but, checking `ros2 pkg executables` there are no executables.

I have the following directory

```
.ros2_ws/install/ros1_bridge
  |_ include
  |_ lib
     |_ libros1_bridge.so
     |_ python3.5
     |_ ros1_bridge
        |_ EXECUTABLES should be here but are not present.
  |_ share
```

Do you know why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304793/colcon-build-ros1_bridge-not-producing-executable/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible that when you built the workspace for the merged install directory the ROS 1 environment was not sourced?

For the ros1_bridge libraries and binaries to be built, there must be some ROS 1 libraries and messages available in the environment. There are instructions in the README: https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge#building-the-bridge-from-source

I was able to reproduce the "missing" files in both merged and isolated install spaces and produce complete installations of the ros1_bridge in both when sourcing a ROS 1 workspace.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2018-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-10-04**:
Thank you, I didn't noticed that part in the README and probably for some reason I had the ROS1 environment sourced when I compiled the first time.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2018-10-04**:
@alsora do you mind updating your question title to be ros1_bridge specific. I think it has the potential to help others who encounter the same issue but the title won't be searchable for someone having issues with the ros1_bridge rather than with --merge-install.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-10-04**:
Sure! I have also sent a PR to that repo, since using Colcon there was not even a warning message that something was missing... That's why I was searching the solution somewhere else rather than in the ros1_bridge docs